# Which enchants are worth the most money?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In terms of gold return. If I'm levelling enchanting by enchanting iron daggers, which enchant gives the dagger the most value? Assuming I'm using just petty/lesser souls.

Comment: Banish is the best for weapons, but what about armor?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The value of the enchantment effect in Skyrim seems to be inversely proportional to the # of base uses for that enchantment.

With a ratio of 5.5, the Banish effect gives you the most money per item.  You can easily make iron daggers with banish that's worth more than 2000 septiums with a lesser soul gem.

For armor and jewelry enchantments, the Waterbreathing effect is the most valuable for petty soul gems and Fortify Sneak for anything with lesser soul gems or higher.  But Banish easily out classes any armor enchantments in terms of profit.

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchantments)

Answer (score 8):

[Apparently the Banish Enchantment.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects#Notes)

"If you are mass enchanting your items, it is more profitable to do so with weapons. Weapon enchant prices are calculated by base uses; the fewer base uses an enchant has, the more expensive the enchantment will be. The Banish enchantment is by far the most profitable weapon enchantment."

Comment: Adds about 1000g to an item's price, at minimum, even with petty souls.

Answer (score 7):

You can make a lot of money from enchanting all kinds of things found in the game.

I'm not sure how z calculated the proportions they mentioned but here are the Weapon Enchantments sorted by base cost:

```
113 Banish
034 Paralyze
031 Absorb Health
029 Turn Undead
029 Damage Stamina
022 Absorb Stamina
021 Absorb Magicka
016 Fear
015 Damage Magicka
014 Shock
011 Fire
010 Frost
009 Soul Trap
```

And here are the Apparel Enchantments sorted by base cost:

```
672 Sneak
393 Carry Weight
369 Two-Handed
369 One-Handed
352 Archery
256 Destruction
251 Healing Rate
246 Conjuration
236 Smithing
235 Block
231 Restoration
226 Illusion
206 Barter Prices
206 Alteration
202 Health
196 Resist Shock
188 Magicka
187 Resist Magic
186 Resist Frost
184 Pickpocket
176 Resist Fire
168 Lockpicking
167 Alchemy
161 Stamina
157 Heavy Armor
137 Light Armor
125 Stamina Regen
105 Muffle
100 Waterbreathing
088 Unarmed
055 Resist Disease
053 Magicka Regen
039 Resist Poison
```

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aEnchantments)