# What is the most efficient way to level up my blacksmithing while conserving as much of my resources as possible?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok so on skyrim I decided to start a new game and play as a argonian blacksmith. Now as I am only level 3 at the moment what is the quickest way to level up my smithing while using the smallest amount of resources possible?

Comment: Just so you know, leveling up the non-combat skills first will make the enemies level up as well and you will have a hard time dealing with them, due to having very low combat skills.

Comment: @Chippies This is offset a bit if the skill is blacksmithing, as your weapons and armor will be awesome, even if you aren't. Joining the Companions for weapons and armor training is a good next step.

Comment: Maybe not quite a duplicate, but I wouldn't argue if somebody voted to close: [What is an effective way to level smithing?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35541/108003)

Comment: @DCShannon I would definitely agree that the linked question is pretty much the exact same thing as this one, minus the focus on "using the smallest amount of resources". That said, the answers accumulating on this question are nearly identical to the other, so I would be strongly inclined to mark this as a dupe.

Comment: @MageXy The focus on efficiency is why I'm not voting, but, like I said, not going to argue against it.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/102844/9192

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the crafting skills, experience gain is based on the *value* of the created item.

- Look at the Items you know how to make. Take the value of the object to be created and divide by the value of it's ingredients.  The item with the biggest ratio will, by definition, give you the most experience for minimal resources.
- Honing an item usually adds significantly to it's value, but I don't believe you can see the the final value before doing so. Experiment at least once at each skill level to find out exactly what your profits will be.  This will become increasingly important as you graduate beyond making "perkless" garbage and your effective skill level gets almost doubled.  Also, cache the best Smithing enchantment you find in each relevant apparel slot.
- Gems have little use other than either selling or, for a small number of quests, giving away.  You might as well earn smithing experience from them by turning them into jewelry before you sell them.  Use the Transmute spell to upgrade cheap Iron Ore to Silver or Gold. High *value/experience*.  Little to no *profit*.
- Dwarven metal is ridiculously abundant.  Take advantage of this fact by purchaseing the [Dwarven Smithing](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dwarven_Smithing) perk and making large numbers of honed dwarven bows. (Bows are the high profit item associated with *this* perk.
- The [Ancient Knowledge](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ancient_Knowledge) power earned for completing the quest [Unfathomable Depths](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unfathomable_Depths) allows you to gain Smithing skill 15% faster.

In the end, if you approach your Smithing like a businessman (businessgecko?), your experience will progress at it's best rate.

---

Interesting Profit Ratios by perk (as compiled from pages linked from [uesp's Smithing page](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing)):

- Perkless

  - Iron Armor 2.84
  - Nord Hero Battle Axe 3.09 (Perhaps not that interesting.  By the time you've "rejuvenated" the Skyforge, you'll have much better options.)
  - Jewelry ~1 (Don't buy the materials, but when you *do* find a Flawless Diamond, you might as well make an amulet with a value of 1200 from it.)
- Steel

  - Steel Armor 2.86 (While only a marginal improvement in profit ratio over Iron, due to having a perk, honing at the Armorer's Table will effectively use almost double your skill level.)
  - Bonemold Helmet 2.88
- **Dwarven - Bow 4.03**
- Elven

  - Elven Warhammer 2.42
  - **Chitin Heavy Armor 7.22**
- **Orcish - Armor 5.10**
- Advanced - **Steel Plate Armor 5.39**
- Arcane Blacksmithing - At this point and beyond, you'll probably get the most advantage from honing found, enchanted objects for which you have the relevant perk, but for the sake of completeness...
- Glass - Bow 2.98
- Ebony

  - Ebony Bow 3.2
  - Stalhrim Bow 3.0
- Daedric - Warhammer 3.96
- Dragonbone - If you've got this perk, you don't need experience.

Comment: Pretty sure you get good profit from crafting gems into jewelry, rather than selling them.

Comment: @DCShannon: According to UESP, you make a profit of 100 by making either a Gold Ruby or Gold Diamond Necklace, but given the value of the materials, the profit ratios are only 1.22 and 1.09 respectively.  So when you find a Gem, make Jewelry, but *don't* buy Gems for the privilege.  A handful of Dwarven Bows will be as much experience and more profitable.

Comment: @DCShannon: In particular, Gold & Gem rings have a profit ratio of 1 (no profit) but they are worth as much experience as 2-3 dwarven bows.  Again, make 'em when you can, but don't go out of your way.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is looting Dwemer ruins (Mzulft is a good one, I've just returned with enough metal for 436 ingots after smelting) for Dwarven Metal Ingots, then use these to make Dwarven arrows. This is also fairly practical if you're an archer (you can't shoot necklaces...)
However, this is useless until level 30 and you have the dwarven smithing perk. Another downside being, it takes forever to chop firewood.

If you're up for a bit of theft, the blacksmith in Solitude usually has Iron and Silver ingots (and a couple of pieces of Iron ore too) that he won't miss. These regenerate after a few in-game days, so you can always grab more.

Comment: Profit ratio on Dwarven Arrows is 2.74.  (Not Bad.  The best ratio among arrows.)  But, as an archer, between Thieves' Caches and/or Hunter's Discipline, you won't need to make too many before the ingots can be put to better use for purposes of leveling Smithing.