# Where can I mine Soul gems at?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can you acquire massive amounts of Soul Gems?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36374/where-can-you-acquire-massive-amounts-of-soul-gems)

I have looked all over for a spot to mine Soul gems and I never found a place.  I want to be able to mine them so I don't have to buy them.

Answer (score 6):

Blackreach has some of the required Geode ore deposits.

Comment: Do u know of any more place's? I'll go down there but still want places that are easier to get to. But thnx for that answer man.

Comment: Blackreach is the only place where you can mine soulgems.

Comment: Blackreach can only be entered by exploring Aftland or Mzinchaelft.